# How to limit number of elements responsively

Tags: jquery, css, html, responsive-design

I want to limit the number of elements in a list. I would like to set the number of elements dynamically.

My first approach was the following:

```
var winHeight = $(window).height() ;
var listHeight = $('.listElement').height() * $('.listElement').length ;

if ( listHeight > (winHeight * 0.66) ){

    // If the list is larger than 66% of the screen, cut off those elements 
    // and provide buttons to flick through the list

}
```

It doesn't look good and I'm not sure if this is the correct way to code this.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Is this something similar you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/vTfRP/

Comment: @Morpheus 
Exactly! Thank you very much!
Only issue is, how do i prevent the last element from being showed half?

Comment: I'm not sure you can as height will be dynamic.

Comment: I guess i will just add a visdually hidden last-child. Thank you for your efforts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why can't you use css solution instead of jQuery?

I didn't understand so much, but on your listElement class, try to do this:

```
.listElement {
  max-height: 300px; // put here your max height do you want
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto; // when your list get the maximum height, css will put a scroolbar
}
```

I'm sorry if a didn't understand it.

Hugs,
Vin.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but i guess i described the issue poorly.
Your suggestion would set the height of my list-elements, which is not wanted.
Also, i am aware of the possibility of setting it to overflow: scroll, but this is exactly what i don't want.

Comment: Yeah! That's it. overflow: scroll. Ok. I'll still trying to help you. So, forget scrollbar, ok? Hugs...